# Sending mail by CDO success only if there are two recipients

Tags: email, yahoo, cdo.message

I use CDO to send emails for years and since last month there is a strange behaviour when the recipient is yahoo. I get an error:
 554 5.7.1 : Data command rejected: SMTP authentication is required for Yahoo mail delivery
However, if I enter TWO recipients separated by comma (even the same address twice), there is no problem and the mail goes ok!!!

Has anybody faced such a problem? It's crazy, isn't it?

Comment: Do you use any proxies? Did you try to use any other ways of sending emails? Do they have the same requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems yahoo has introduced a new security check and do does not accept email from unauthenticated senders of any domain (my case).
So If I enter my email smtp password to send email, there is no problem at all.
Please note that I don't hav a yahoo account, my email is @otenet.gr (which permits unathenticated send mail).

PS
However, the security chek is easily bypassed by just having TWO recipients...